# LaTeX package for writing algorithms

Tags: algorithm, latex, package

which package would you use for writing algorithms in LaTeX? I know about algorithm, algorithmic and algorithms packages.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [listings package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) is what you are looking for.
[alt text http://files.droplr.com/files/35740123/13etch.listings.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/35740123/13etch.listings.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'd add to your list [algorithm2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/).

Comment: In my experience, algorithm2e is more trouble than its worth. I found it is not very compatible with some journal and conference document classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use Algorithmic for algorithms and psuedocode writing.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode